# template parameter with default value for class

Tags: c++, c++11, template-meta-programming, sfinae, type-traits

I dont quite understand below code, there are two parameters for the template, the second one has `class = xxxx`, This seems strange to me. Can you explain it to me how should I understand it? and besides `std::enable_if`, is there any other use case for this c++ *feature*?

```
template < class T,
class = typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value>::type>
bool is_even (T i) {return !bool(i%2);}
```

Comment: It's a defaulted template parameter without a name. The main "other use case" is in constructor templates, since constructors don't have a return type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One word: SFINAE.

Substitution Failure Is Not An Error.

Look for that word with google and a whole new world will open up for you.

Let see the meaning of your code.

```
std::is_integral<typename T>::value
```

It's a boolean value, dependant from type `T`, with value `true` if `T` is a integral type, `false` otherwise.

```
std::enable_if<bool B, typename T = void>::type
```

It's the type `T`, when `B == true`, nothing otherwise.

So, in your code

```
template < class T,
class = typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value>::type>
```

when `T` is a integral type, the second (unnamed) template argument is substituted with a type (the default: `void`; but, in this case, the exact type is irrelevant) and the function is activated. On the contrary, when `T` isn't a integral type, there is the failure in the substitution of the second template argument and this version of the `is_even()` function isn't activated (for type `T`) and, this is the important point, it isn't an error (another version of `is_even()` can be activated).

More interesting can be see how to implement an alternative version of `is_even()`, for non integral types. You can think that you can implement another version that negate `std::is_integral`

```
template < class T,
class = typename std::enable_if<false == std::is_integral<T>::value>::type>
```

but this don't work (is an error and don't compile) because you have two `is_even()` templated function that differs (from the templates arguments point of view) only for a default argument.

A solution can apply SFINAE to the return value

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<true == std::is_integral<T>::value, bool>::type
is_even (T const & i)
 { return ! (i%2); }

template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<false == std::is_integral<T>::value, bool>::type
is_even (T const &)
 { return false; }


int main()
 {
   std::cout << "-- is 7 even ?     " << is_even(7) << '\n';
   std::cout << "-- is 8UL even ?   " << is_even(8LL) << '\n';
   std::cout << "-- is \"abc\" even ? " << is_even("abc") << '\n';

   return 0;
 }
```

In this way you have a version of `is_even()` enabled for integral type and a second version (that return even `false`) for non integral types.

p.s.: sorry for my bad english.